WSO2 Micro Integrator: Issue with Aggregating Responses from Multiple Data Services
I'm facing an issue while trying to aggregate responses from multiple data services using WSO2 Micro Integrator. Here's the situation and problem description:
Background:
    I have a WSO2 Micro Integrator instance configured with an API named CombinedAPI.
    The API is designed to aggregate data from three data services (usersDS, officesDS, productsDS), each fetching user, office, and product data from separate MySQL databases.
    The API context is set to /aggregate with a resource configured to accept OfficeCode and category_id as path parameters in the URI template.

Problem Description:
    Individual service responses (from usersDS, officesDS, productsDS) are working correctly.
    However, the combined API is not returning the expected aggregated results.
    The userData, officeData, and productData fields in the final response are empty, suggesting an issue with how responses are being aggregated.
    The properties (userResponse, officeResponse, productResponse) are not being correctly set or accessed in the payload factory, leading to incomplete aggregation.

Configuration Snippets:
Here's a snippet of the CombinedAPI configuration:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/aggregate" name="CombinedAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/getData/{OfficeCode}/{category_id}">
        <inSequence>
            <!-- Capture URI variables -->
            <property name="OfficeCode" expression="get-property('uri.var.OfficeCode')"/>
            <property name="category_id" expression="get-property('uri.var.category_id')"/>

            <clone>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/usersDS/getUsers"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log level="full" separator=",">
                            <property name="User Service Response" expression="get-property('response')"/>
                        </log>
                        <property name="userResponse" expression="get-property('response')"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/officesDS/getOffice/{uri.var.OfficeCode}"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log level="full" separator=",">
                            <property name="Office Service Response" expression="get-property('response')"/>
                        </log>
                        <property name="officeResponse" expression="get-property('response')"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/productsDS/getProduct/{uri.var.category_id}"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log level="full" separator=",">
                            <property name="Product Service Response" expression="get-property('response')"/>
                        </log>
                        <property name="productResponse" expression="get-property('response')"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>

            <aggregate>
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="3"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete expression="json-eval($)">
                    <log level="full" separator=",">
                        <property name="Aggregated Response" expression="json-eval($)"/>
                    </log>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>
                            {
                                "userData": $1,
                                "officeData": $2,
                                "productData": $3
                            }
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="get-property('userResponse')"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="get-property('officeResponse')"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="get-property('productResponse')"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <log level="full" separator=",">
                        <property name="Final Response" expression="json-eval($)"/>
                    </log>
                    <respond/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

Also, here are snippets of the data service configurations (productsDS and officesDS) involved in the aggregation:
productsDS
<data transports="http https" serviceGroup="" serviceNamespace="" name="productsDS">
  <description>Service to expose product data</description>
  <query id="readProduct" useConfig="db3">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = ?</sql>
    <param name="category_id" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN" />
    <result outputType="json">
      {
        "products": {
          "product": [
            {
              "name": "$name",
              "description": "$description",
              "price": "$price"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    </result>
  </query>
  <config id="db3">
    <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/products</property>
    <property name="username">root</property>
    <property name="password" />
  </config>
  <resource returnRequestStatus="true" path="getProduct/{category_id}" method="GET">
    <description>Retrieve products by category_id</description>
    <call-query href="readProduct">
      <with-param name="category_id" query-param="category_id" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
</data>

(officesDS):
<data transports="http https" serviceGroup="" serviceNamespace="" name="officesDS">
  <description>Service to expose office data</description>
  <query id="readOffice" useConfig="db2">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM offices WHERE OfficeCode = ?</sql>
    <param name="OfficeCode" sqlType="STRING" type="IN" />
    <result outputType="json">
      {
        "offices": {
          "office": [
            {
              "AddressLine1": "$AddressLine1",
              "City": "$City",
              "Phone": "$Phone"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    </result>
  </query>
  <resource returnRequestStatus="true" path="getOffice/{OfficeCode}" method="GET">
    <description>Retrieve an office by OfficeCode</description>
    <call-query href="readOffice">
      <with-param name="OfficeCode" query-param="OfficeCode" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <config id="db2">
    <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/officedetails</property>
    <property name="username">root</property>
    <property name="password" />
  </config>
</data>

**Snippet of the log : **
[2024-06-18 21:58:55,738] INFO {LogMediator} - {api
} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid
, correlation_id: ddae71aa-f861-48bc-9371-ec24611e7b9b_5a3a0a72-a48d-4d45-b67b-b3c441c835f1_418de026-5097-40b9-a64c-c44e627e1a8c, Direction: request, Aggregated Raw Response = [{"products":{"product":{"price":59.99,"name":"Levi's 501 Jeans","description":"Classic Levi's 501 jeans for men"}}},{"users":{"user":[{"user_id":1,"first_name":"david","username":"rogers63"},{"user_id":2,"first_name":"rogers","username":"mike28"},{"user_id":3,"first_name":"david","username":"rivera92"},{"user_id":4,"first_name":"maria","username":"ross95"},{"user_id":5,"first_name":"morris","username":"paul85"},{"user_id":6,"first_name":"daniel","username":"smith34"},{"user_id":7,"first_name":"sanders","username":"james84"},{"user_id":8,"first_name":"mark","username":"daniel53"},{"user_id":9,"first_name":"morgan","username":"brooks80"},{"user_id":10,"first_name":"paul","username":"morgan65"}]}},{"offices":{"office":{"AddressLine1":"123 Main St","Phone":"123-456-7890","City":"New York"}}}], Payload: [{"products":{"product":{"price":59.99,"name":"Levi's 501 Jeans","description":"Classic Levi's 501 jeans for men"}}},{"users":{"user":[{"user_id":1,"first_name":"david","username":"rogers63"},{"user_id":2,"first_name":"rogers","username":"mike28"},{"user_id":3,"first_name":"david","username":"rivera92"},{"user_id":4,"first_name":"maria","username":"ross95"},{"user_id":5,"first_name":"morris","username":"paul85"},{"user_id":6,"first_name":"daniel","username":"smith34"},{"user_id":7,"first_name":"sanders","username":"james84"},{"user_id":8,"first_name":"mark","username":"daniel53"},{"user_id":9,"first_name":"morgan","username":"brooks80"},{"user_id":10,"first_name":"paul","username":"morgan65"}]}},{"offices":{"office":{"AddressLine1":"123 Main St","Phone":"123-456-7890","City":"New York"}}}]
[2024-06-18 21:58:55,738] INFO {LogMediator} - {api
} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid
, correlation_id: ddae71aa-f861-48bc-9371-ec24611e7b9b_5a3a0a72-a48d-4d45-b67b-b3c441c835f1_418de026-5097-40b9-a64c-c44e627e1a8c, Direction: request, Final Response = {
"userData": ,
"officeData": ,
"productData":
}, Payload: {
"userData": ,
"officeData": ,
"productData":
}


Troubleshooting Attempts:
I've ensured that individual services (usersDS, officesDS, productsDS) are functioning correctly.
Reviewed the payload factory and complete condition in the CombinedAPI configuration.
Checked logs indicating successful retrieval of data from each service but incomplete aggregation in the final response.
Question:
How can I troubleshoot and resolve the issue of incomplete aggregation in WSO2 Micro Integrator's CombinedAPI? Are there specific configurations or adjustments required in the payload factory or elsewhere to ensure proper aggregation and population of userData, officeData, and productData fields in the final response?

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on resolving this issue and optimizing the aggregation process in WSO2 Micro Integrator would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
